# Powershell - Select-Objects from previous commands

Tags: powershell, dhcp, scope-id

I can't seem to understand how to get a previous-command-object displayed on the final table in powershell. I understand I'm not explaining myself that well, so I'll go with the examples :)

```
get-dhcpserverv4scope -computername server01
```

This will return me something like this:

ScopeID,SubnetMask,Name

10.0.10.0,255.255.255.0,Scope1

10.5.0.0,255.255.248.0,Scope2

Now, when I run this instead I can't get ScopeID to be displayed with the second command results:

```
get-dhcpserverv4scope -computername server01 | ForEach-Object {get-dhcpserverv4optionvalue -computername server01 -scopeid $_.scopeid} | where {$_.OptionID -like "6"} | Select-Object Name, OptionID, Value
```

I obviously get to select the Objects from the get-dhcpserverv4optionvalue. How can I get also the ScopeID included in the latest Select-Object?
Is it actually possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Add-Member to add a property to the each object returned by `dhcpserverv4optionvalue`:

```
(get-dhcpserverv4optionvalue -computername server01 -scopeid $_.scopeid) | 
Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ScopeID " -Value $_.ScopeID -PassThru
```

The full oneliner will be:

`get-dhcpserverv4scope -computername server01 | 
 ForEach-Object 
 {(get-dhcpserverv4optionvalue -computername server01 -scopeid $_.scopeid) | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ScopeID " -Value $_.ScopeID -PassThru} | 
 where {$_.OptionID -like "6"} | Select-Object Name, OptionID, Value`

Comment: To see the members of the last object you can replace the last select-object with get-member. Then you will see if the property exists. If it exists then it's value may be null.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but this should work:

```
get-dhcpserverv4scope -computername server01 | ForEach-Object {
    $ScopeID = $_.ScopeID
    get-dhcpserverv4optionvalue -computername server01 -scopeid $_.scopeid
} | where {
    $_.OptionID -like "6"
}  | Select-Object Name, OptionID, Value, @{L='ScopeID';E={$ScopeID}}
```

I am basically saving the ScopeID value within the ForEach statement and then using at the end by creating a custom property at the end.